# Mysql stored procedure not working anymore after server change

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, server, migration

Ok, I have an app, which was working.
IT department moved it to a new server.
It still works... except for ONE thing... which uses a mysql stored procedure.

From the "user click", to the mysql.log : everything is fine.
I successfully find the procedure call in it, with appropriate parameters:
`10462020 Query CALL deleteUpdateOrder(468, 1)`
But, on the database side, nothing happens. (And there are no error message in the log file)

I checked the procedure, it indeed exists too in the new server:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`tice`@`%` PROCEDURE `deleteUpdateOrder`(IN `s_id` INT, IN `deleted_q_order` INT)
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM questions WHERE session_id=s_id AND q_order=deleted_q_order;
    UPDATE questions
        SET q_order = q_order-1
    WHERE q_order > deleted_q_order
    AND session_id=s_id;
END
```

As there was some username changes between servers, just in case I added permission to my user 'qamphi' to have permission on it (don't think it was needed with the ALL PRIVILEGES line, but just in case) :

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for qamphi@localhost                                                                                   |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `qamphi`@`localhost` IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'RANDOM_DATA_HERE' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `qamphi`.* TO `qamphi`@`localhost`                                                    |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `qamphi`.`qamphi` TO `qamphi`@`localhost`                                             |
| GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE `qamphi`.`deleteupdateorder` TO `qamphi`@`localhost`                               |
| GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE `qamphi`.`proposaldelete` TO `qamphi`@`localhost`                                  |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Everything seems in place, yet it's not updated in the DB... I'm out of idea, does anyone has any clue on this ?

Thx a lot in advance.

Comment: Does it do the DELETE and not the UPDATE or the UPDATE and not the DELETE or does it do nothing?

Comment: The code looks so simple that it cannot fail - perhaps the data is not as you expect and the code finds nothing to do.

Comment: Nothing AT ALL happens, and the data is fine, it should do what it has to do. :(

Comment: Have you granted necessary privs to `tice` user? The default [`SQL SECURITY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-objects-security.html#stored-objects-security-sql-security) is `DEFINER`, not `INVOKER`.

Comment: Ho really good question, I'm afraid this account isn't on the new server! I'll give it a try, thx!

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't work/ I created back the user with execute privilege on the proc, and still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, while I'm not sure WHY, I was able to fix my problem.

Instead of recreating and granting rights to the missing user (which didn"t work, meh), I edited the stored procedure changing the definer in the `mysql`.`proc` table, and it worked instantly.

I guess it's one ugly fix, but after weeks of disfunctionning live application, it's still a relief...